# My computer is extremely slow with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.04, hp

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a HP Pavilion 7000 with "graphics driver" VESA: NV31 Board-e133nz. I have no idea what graphic card is in the machine.

The installation seemed to be good. Then, booting from the HD, the screen went black. I had to use a separate monitor to see, but just before the login screen, this monitor also went black.

I booted in safe mode and only the separate monitor worked. I tried many sudo commands that I saw on the internet but nothing worked. I then went to the bumbelebee site and installed their driver, and now I can boot and see the laptop monitor.

However, the computer is so slow that I have to wait 6 1/2 minutes for it to boot. I timed it and all the other stuff is just as slow.

Comment: The video adapter in the HP Pavilion 7000 is S3 Trio 64/32.

Comment: machine specs are important. not all can google just to see specifications of Pavilion 700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your computer is a bit low on resources. I'd check RAM first. But based on my personal experience (I've always used older and low resource machines) I'd recommend you to give Lubuntu a try. It's much lighter than Ubuntu.